# How to write a line by line to a file in Erlang

Tags: file-io, erlang, newline

As in the title or how to write to a new line in Erlang?

Thank You!

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`io:fwrite`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#fwrite-1) functions. See [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20111102201547/http://www.erlang.org/article/11) and this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/erlang/erlang_file_input_output.htm) for examples.

Here is a short snippet to showcase,

```erlang
39> {ok, FD} = file:open("test.txt",[read, write]).
{ok,<0.130.0>}
40> io:fwrite(FD, "First line  ~n", []).
ok
41> io:fwrite(FD, "Second line  ~n", []).
ok
```