# Writing a string in newline

Tags: file, erlang, ejabberd

How can we append a string in a file i newline in erlang?
Till now I have done this:

```
file:write_file("test5.txt", "\\nAbh~~nimanyu", [append]).
file:write_file("test5.txt", "\nAbh~nimanyu", [append]).
```

Yes, it is writing the string in file, but it is not writing the string in newline.

Output in file is like this:

```
Abh~nimanyu\nAbh~nimanyu
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write a line by line to a file in Erlang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253630/how-to-write-a-line-by-line-to-a-file-in-erlang)

Comment: the answer in that link solves your issue more times than you might think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the newline format sequence `~n` or `\n` for creating strings with newlines when using the format string functions.

The issue is `file:write_file` is expecting an unformatted string and will not convert `~n` to newlines automatically.

`io_lib:format` and `io_lib:fwrite` will properly expand strings with format expressions like `~n`, `~p`, `~s`, etc. and return the formatted string.

The following should give the expected result:

```erlang
Formatted = io_lib:format("\nAbh~nimanyu", []),
file:write_file("test5.txt", Formatted, [append]).
```

Alternatively you could just use `\n` and skip the `io_lib:format` function:

```erlang
file:write_file("test5.txt", "\nAbh\nimanyu", [append]).
```